# How to check if someone on the same network accessed/tried to access my shared resources

Tags: windows, network-shares, remote-access, shared-folders

Simply I have shared some folders on my system in Windows 8. I just want to know who on the same network accessed or at least tried to access them.

thank you.

Comment: Check your firewall log.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Could you please tell how do I check the logs.

Comment: Well, depends on your firewall.  For Norton you'd right-click on the toolbar icon and select "View Recent History".

Comment: Just Windows Firewall

Comment: Go to Computer Management and under System Tools, there is "Shared Folders". You can check for "Open Files" those are files that are currently being accessed by users on your network.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a program called [Sharewatch](http://stevemiller.net/sharewatch/). It allows you to view who is currently connected and what files they are accessing within your shared folders. You can show the user name, IP and computer name of connected users and you can disconnect users that you don't want on your shared folders. Usage is pretty self explanatory - just expand the categories until you see what you need to.

[Sharemonitor](http://csharptips.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/monitoring-access-to-your-shared-files-on-network/) is a similar program that also shows recent access history and saves log files.

Comment: Does it show the history also?

Comment: Unfortunately I think not. Edited to include an alternative